# Filtering output from wget using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, wget

How would I go about taking the output from a post call made using wget and filtering out everything but a string I want using sed. In other words, let's say I have some wget call that returns (amongst part of some string) :

```
'userPreferences':'some stuff' }
```

How would I get the string "some stuff" such that the command would look something like:

```
sed whatever-command-here | wget my-post-parameters some-URL
```

Also is that the proper way to chain the two as one line?

Comment: You might have better luck sedding the output from wget over running wget reading output from a sed of standard input.  I suggest a primer on shell scripting before trying to write shell scripts.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe works the other way around. They chain the left command's output to the right command's input:

```
wget ... | sed -n "/'userPreferences':/{s/[^:]*://;s/}$//p}" # keeps quotes
```

The filtering might be easier to express with `GNU grep` though:

```
wget ... | grep -oP "(?<='userPreferences':').*(?=' })" # strips the quotes, too
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the output of `wget` to go to `sed`, so the order would be `wget foo | sed bar`

```
wget -q -O - someurl | sed ...
```

The `-q` flag will silence most of `wget`'s output and `-O -` will write to standard output, so you can then pipe everything to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a system that supports named pipes (FIFOs) or the `/dev/fd` method of naming open files, you could avoid a pipe and use `< <(...)`

```
sed whatever-command-here < <(wget my-post-parameters some-URL)
```